# JOOQ: how to use multiset

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

Given these 3 tables with a many-to-many relationship

**book**

| book_id | title | isbn | num_pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JOOQ | 1234 | 123 |
| 2 | SQL | 2345 | 155 |

**book_author**

| book_id | author_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

**author**

| author_id | author_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Lucas |
| 2 | Jose |

And records

```java
public record Book(Integer id, String title, String isbn, List<Author> authors) {}// don't need nr of pages

public record Author(Integer id, String name){}
```

How to get a `List<Book>` using multiset?

```java
List<Book> books = dsl.select(
        BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOK_ID,
        select(BOOK.TITLE).from(BOOK).where(BOOK.BOOK_ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOK_ID)).asField("title"),
        select(BOOK.ISBN).from(BOOK).where(BOOK.BOOK_ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOK_ID)).asField("isbn"),
        multiset(
                selectFrom(AUTHOR).where(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID.eq(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID))
        ).as("authors").convertFrom(record -> record.map(Records.mapping(Author::new)))
).from(BOOK_AUTHOR)
 .where(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOK_ID.in(1, 2))
 .fetchInto(Book.class);

 books.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Expected a list with **2** books, but getting **3** books instead !?...

```
Book{id=1, title='JOOQ', isbn='1234', authors=[Author{name='Lucas'}]}
Book{id=2, title='SQL', isbn='2345', authors=[Author{name='Lucas'}]}
Book{id=2, title='SQL', isbn='2345', authors=[Author{name='Jose'}]}
```

What is the problem?

The generated SQL:

```
select "public"."book_author"."book_id", (select "public"."book"."title" from "public"."book" where "public"."book"."book_id" = "public"."book_author"."book_id") as "title", (select "public"."book"."isbn" from "public"."book" where "public"."book"."book_id" = "public"."book_author"."book_id") as "isbn", (select coalesce(jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_array("v0", "v1")), jsonb_build_array()) from (select "public"."author"."author_id" as "v0", "public"."author"."author_name" as "v1" from "public"."author" where "public"."author"."author_id" = "public"."book_author"."author_id") as "t") as "authors" from "public"."book_author" where "public"."book_author"."book_id" in (1, 2)
```

Used:

- JAVA 17
- POSTGRESQL
- spring-boot (2.6.1) with spring-boot-starter-jooq
- JOOQ 3.15.4 (allows the use of the `multiset` function)
- JOOQ code generation (maven plugin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting from BOOK_AUTHOR that has 3 entries. You should select from BOOK:

```java
List<Book> books = dsl.select(
   BOOK.BOOK_ID,
   BOOK.TITLE,
   BOOK.ISBN,
   multiset(
     select(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID,AUTHOR.AUTHOR_NAME)
         .from(AUTHOR).innerJoin(BOOK_AUTHOR)
         .on(BOOK_AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID.eq(AUTHOR.AUTHOR_ID))
         .where(BOOK_AUTHOR.BOOK_ID.eq(BOOK.BOOK_ID))
    ).as("authors")
     .convertFrom(record -> record.map(Records.mapping(Author::new)))
    ).from(BOOK)
     .where(BOOK.BOOK_ID.in(1, 2))
     .fetchInto(Book.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting errors with this code... but I get your point

Comment: Works fine after some small changes. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy you found the issue